# Mean Square Differentiability for M estimation- Example

Tags: econometrics, nonparametrics

Newey's 1994 paper on Semi Parametric Estimation mentions a condition in two step semi parametric estimation.

Suppose that $h$ is an (infinite) dimensional nuisance parameter that is estimated non parametrically. In the second step, we estimate a finite dimensional parameter of interest $\theta$. The true values $h_0$ of $h$ and $\theta_0$ of $\theta$ satisfy
$\mathbb{E}[m(W;\theta_0,h_0)]=0$.
We use a non parametric method that yields an estimator $\hat{h}$ of $h_0$.
We then find $\hat{\theta}$
as a solution to $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n m(W_i,\hat{\theta}_{n},h_0)=0$.

In one of conditions, Newey mentions the mean square differentiability, and in the papers he   mentions ways to find candidates.

Suppose that the $m( . , ., h)$ is Frechet differentiable in $h$, and suppose we have a linear map $D(w,h-h_0)$ that this the linearization of $m(h)$ at $h_0$.
Are there example any examples of finding if possible and one showing that it is not possible a sequence a function $\alpha$ such that $\mathbb{E}[D(w,\hat{h}-h_0)]-\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha(w_i)}{n}$ converges to $0$ in prob. (Detailed Examples) Of course, I need $$\mathbb{E}[D(w,\hat{h}-h_0)]$$ to be non zero.